# Generate time series between two datetimes

Tags: python

I have tried to generate an ordered dictionary given two Python datetime values. Example:

```
s = datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,50)
e = datetime(2020,4,7,00,00,02)

d = f(s,e)

print(d)

OrderedDict([
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,50): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,51): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,52): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,53): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,54): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,55): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,56): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,57): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,58): None,
    datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,59): None,
    datetime(2020,4,7,0,0,0): None,
    datetime(2020,4,7,0,0,1): None,
    datetime(2020,4,7,0,0,2): None
    ])
```

Seems like not that straightforward as it seems. Any reference on this or there is actually a package out there so that I don't need to reinvent an (very much possible) ugly wheel?

Comment: Is there a pattern to the times within the series and if so, what is it? If not, then you're going to have to explicitly enumerate each of them.

Comment: @martineau - thanks for the comment! the only thing i need will be the list of all the seconds. i have tried to use a nested loop and a yield function but the logic is getting messy when it comes to the case that i need to loop across multiple days. i think i can probably break it down to enumerate those within the same date and the use the time of the end date to wrap up

Comment: In that case you should be able use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to compute each of the intermediate times.  You can also use [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) to create a dictionary of `None` values from them.

Comment: Note that since `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, it has an `OrderedDict.fromkeys()` class method just like the baseclass does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def generate_range(start_date, end_date):
    delta = end_date - start_date
    return [start_date + timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(delta.seconds + 1)]

s = datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,50)
e = datetime(2020,4,7,0,0,2)
print(generate_range(s,e))
```

It will generate a list of datetimes for each second between the `start_date` and the `end_date` provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import OrderedDict

s = datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,50)
e = datetime(2020,4,7,00,00,2)

def time_series(s,e):
    return OrderedDict([(s+timedelta(seconds=i),None) for i in range((e-s).seconds+1)])

print(time_series(s,e))
```

This function will generate your OrderedDict.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using `datetime.timedelta` and `OrderedDict.fromkeys()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint


def series_generator(start, end, delta_time):
    """ Generate a series of datetimes between the `start` and `end`
        datetimes with a `delta_time` between each one.
    """
    tm = start
    while tm <= end:
        yield tm
        tm += delta_time


start = datetime(2020,4,6,23,59,50)
end = datetime(2020,4,7,0,0,2)
delta_time = timedelta(seconds=1)
res = OrderedDict.fromkeys(series_generator(start, end, delta_time))
pprint(res)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([(datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 50), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 51), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 52), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 53), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 54), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 55), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 56), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 57), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 58), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 23, 59, 59), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7, 0, 0), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7, 0, 0, 1), None),
             (datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 7, 0, 0, 2), None)])
```